# express middleware with regards to the logic of a server

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt

I'm learning how to build server with authentication. I'm following this [tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-authentication-easier-with-json-web-token-cc15df3f2228), the final code can be found [here](https://github.com/sudheeshshetty/JWT_Auth). Which uses `Express` and `JWT` to build a simple login server. The following code:

```
app.use((req, res, next)=>{
        // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
        console.log(req.body);
        var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
        if(token){
          console.log("token");
          jwt.verify(token,"samplesecret",(err,decod)=>{
            if(err){
              res.status(403).json({
                message:"Wrong Token"
              });
            }
            else{
              console.log("success");
              req.decoded=decod;
              next();
            }
          });
        }
        else{
          res.status(403).json({
            message:"No Token"
          });
        }
});
```

is adding a middleware, but I'm not sure what the purpose of this is and how it works. Is this being called on every route? What is `req.body` in this case? And what does `res.status().json()` do?

---

I also don't understand what the script `auth` and `getlist` under the HTML file does (too long to include). When are these scripts being called? Are they storing a `cookie` on the user's computer? What's being authenticated?

---

This is a lot of questions and I apologize. I'm quite new to web-dev, just want to figure out the fundaments. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being called on every route to check for an existence of a token, decode, and check it.

If present, and decoded, (where it says `console.log('success');`) it is attaching the data decoded from the jwt to the request `req` so that in any of the controllers where you handle the request you can have the data (stored on `req.decoded`)

---

As far as `res.status().json()` (`res` of course meaning response)...
2 functions are being chained that are functions of `res`.

- `status(int)`
- `json(obj)`

`req.status` sets the response status code (eg 200 OK, 404 Not found, 503 Server error).
`req.json` send the response with the body being the json you pass in.

So the following would send the message {error:'We failed'} back to the client with a http status code of 503:

```
req.status(503).json({ error: 'We failed' });
```

You can read more about response methods/properties like this (and others like `send`, `redirect`, ect) on the Express documentation [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res).

Comment: Say I were to use this, on some route (b/c not all routes need authentication), how am I to check for failure with regards to the status code? I imagine that if successfully authenticated, I could just call `req.body.decoded`, and if not, `req.body.decoded` would not exist, right? So what is the purpose of doing all the other work and sending the status codes? Seems like it's unnecessary?

Comment: Yes you are right request.body.decode will not exist but you need to tell this to you front-end from where you are making the request , it needs to know if the request is successful or not , status codes tells you the status of your request according to which you can display the correct error message to the user.